# "You can't put (a.k.a. dispatch from saga) frozen actions" - Redux Saga

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga, saga

This is my first stackoverflow questions please excuse if there is any mistake.

I am a beginner to react, redux and saga.
I am trying to dispatch an action which will be handled by saga and then dispatch another action from within saga. While I do this I get this below error message :

> "You can't put (a.k.a. dispatch from saga) frozen actions. We have to
> define a special non-enumerable property on those actions for
> scheduling purposes. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to communicate
> properly between sagas & other subscribers (action ordering would
> become far less predictable). If you are using redux and you care
> about this behaviour (frozen actions), then you might want to switch
> to freezing actions in a middleware rather than in action creator.
> Example implementation:
>
> const freezeActions = store => next => action =>
> next(Object.freeze(action))"

I haven't explicitly frozen my actions anywhere. I am just calling a function which returns an action object. I dont understand why saga complains that its frozen object.

I have reproduced my error in this sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-zhukovsky-ntmfn

Answer (score 1):

So solution was very simple. When I was trying to import action creator function I was not importing within {}. Action creator was not a default export from where it was defined.

```
import { setSnackbar } from "../../ducks/snackbar"; //---> senSnackbar should be imported within brackets.
//import setSnackbar from "../../ducks/snackbar"; //->dont do this
import { call, put } from "redux-saga/effects";

export function* handleCheckCoin(action) {
  try {
    let strSymbol = action.payload;
    console.log("Symbol : " + JSON.stringify(strSymbol));
    ///send out a api request to check Crypto Symbol is valid
    yield put(setSnackbar(true, "success", "message"));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error while launching set snack bar action : " + error);
  }
}
```